What is the root cause of Russell's paradox?
We know that Russell's paradox led to the third mathematical crisis. Later, we developed modern set theory, but only to limit the emergence of Russell's paradox, rather than to find the root of the formation of this paradox.

See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/ - There are also several questions on this blog which deal with Russell's paradox. What did you find out by yourself about the issue?

I have studied fundamental mathematical problems and their philosophy for more than thirty years. My conclusion is that we must look philosophically for the root of the problem, and that our different understandings of the concept of infinity will lead to different results. Russell's paradox is an inevitable result of "actual infinite thought," as detailed in my paper.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/377571704_Turing_Machine_Halting_Problem_Russell's_Paradox_and_Godel_Incompleteness_Theorem

Please see the answer of @causative below which is generally accepted as the cause of the Russell paradox, the unrestricted set comprehension. You may also post your question at https://math.stackexchange.com/

See Ivor Grattan-Guinness, How Bertrand Russell discovered his paradox (1978) and Bernard Linsky, Ernst Schroeder and Zermelo's Anticipation of Russell’s Paradox (2013)

And Alejandro Garciadiego, Bertrand Russell and the Origins of the Set-theoretic Paradoxes (Birkhauser, 1992)

Still very useful Bertrand Russell, Mathematical Logic as based on the Theory of Types (American Journal of Mathematics, 1908), I. The Contradictions.

The root cause of Russell's paradox is unrestricted set comprehension. Unrestricted set comprehension is what lets you assume that "the set S of all sets that do not contain themselves" actually exists. Without that assumption, you don't get the paradox, because S does not exist.
Another way of describing this is that Russell's paradox results from axiom systems that let you form sets that are "too big" (or "too self-referential"). S is "too big" and "too self-referential" because it contains the kind of set that S itself is.
One way to resolve this is to say that sets that are "too big" are not actually sets - they are proper classes. If S is the proper class of all sets that do not contain themselves, then there is no paradox. S is not an element of itself because S contains only sets and S is not a set.
